# Why gradle/ivy doesn't download dependencies if they already presented in my maven local repo?

Tags: gradle, ivy

Sometimes my maven repo contains only poms without jars. In this case gradle/ivy rises exception and stops building:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':core:compile'.
> Artifact 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.6@jar' not found.
```

There is repos that have this jar file. Why gradle doesn't check other project repos and stops building? How can tell gradle to check other repos in this case?

**added:**
to solve this problem (`Artifact 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.6@jar' not found.`) I just delete `logback-classic` folder from my maven local repo. Then gradle will download pom/jar from other linked repositories.

Comment: what's your repo layout? how do you describe repo in your build?

Comment: original maven layout. `repositories {
        mavenLocal();
        mavenCentral() }`

Comment: How do you declare the dependency? Please shows us your build script.

Comment: It looks like a bug. Removing local cache helps, but I have to do it too often...

Comment: Just reference, the issue tracked here - http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2034

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Gradle will always take POM and artifacts from the same Maven repository. And since it treats the local Maven repository as just another Maven repository, this is the behavior you get. To make it look for artifacts in other repositories, you can use `repositories { maven { url "..."; artifactUrls "...", "..." } }`. For `mavenLocal` and `mavenCentral`, the syntax is `mavenLocal(artifactUrls: ["...", "..."])`.

Comment: Can I automatically "repair" my local maven repo?